# Javascript not working in Chrome or IE9 - Error "Checkbox is not defined" shows in FF JS console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

The Function is...

```
function checkbox(val) {
    if (val==17831)  {
        document.getElementById

("Public_Product_line_questionpi_Public_Product_line_question_16171").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById
    }
}
```

The DOM Checkbox Element is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="General_Email_Opt_inpi_General_Email_Opt_in_17831" id="General_Email_Opt_inpi_General_Email_Opt_in_17831" value="17831" onchange="piAjax.auditField(this, 9782, 28771, 600841);" onclick="checkbox(17831)"/>
```

Why does this not work in Chrome or IE-9? It works fine in Firefox
Why does the JS console in Chrome state "Uncaught ReferenceError: checkbox is not defined" ?

Comment: With some tweaking (since you were referencing to things you didn't post) this is not causing errors: http://jsfiddle.net/gQtwd/. Are you sure `checkbox` is not inside e.g. an `onload` handler?

Comment: @pimvdb The checkbox is definately not inside an onload handler.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you've posted, I'd say it's because of a JS parsing error. Your code should probably be the following:

```
function checkbox(val) {
  if (val==17831)  {
    document.getElementById("Public_Product_line_questionpi_Public_Product_line_question_16171").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not a parse error the code is

function checkbox(val) {
  if (val==17831)  {
    document.getElementById("Public_Product_line_questionpi_Public_Product_line_question_16171").disabled = false;
  }
}


It does not work in Google Chrome or IE-9